# How does Google validate network connectivity when using NET_CAPABILITY_VALIDATED?

Tags: android, android-source, android-connectivitymanager

Out of curiosity, what method is Google using to validate a working internet connection? Are they hitting a universal endpoint? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkCapabilities#NET_CAPABILITY_VALIDATED

Any link to some AOSP would be very helpful as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question got me curious and searched on [cs.android.com](https://cs.android.com) (AOSP viewer) a bit.
Looks to me that the stack does a probing step here in order to move to VALIDATED state in this part of code [here](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:packages/modules/NetworkStack/src/com/android/server/connectivity/NetworkMonitor.java;drc=master;l=1481)

The first thing it checks is whether we are in a captive portal situation. The default URL to check that is [here](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/ConnectivityService.java;l=277;bpv=0;bpt=1) in ConnectivityService:

```
  private static final String DEFAULT_CAPTIVE_PORTAL_HTTP_URL =
            "http://connectivitycheck.gstatic.com/generate_204";
```

Comment: looks like after the captive portal check, theres a check for a working private dns, then bandwidth if necessary. once these are all satisfied, the VALIDATED state is set.

Comment: Looks like that server is blocked in China: https://www.comparitech.com/privacy-security-tools/blockedinchina/

Comment: Yep, everything Google is. 
https://blog.headuck.com/2020/10/23/how-samsung-devices-connect-qq-baidu-taobao-hao123/